# Out of memory Error when querying fields with special characters using pyodbc with python3

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, out-of-memory, sybase, pyodbc

#### Environment

- Python: 3.4.2
- pyodbc: 4.0.23
- OS: Debian 9
- DB: Sybase 12.5.3
- driver: unixODBC 2.3.1

#### Issue

I´m porting a web application using Django and SQLAlchemy from Python2 to Python3 and everything works just fine, except for queries that do a "SELECT *" to any table. I tested it with this code:

```
connector = "DRIVER={%s};Server=%s;Database=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;TDS_Version=%s;Port=%s;" % my_db
conn = db.connect(connector)
cur = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM My_Table'
cur.execute(query)
row = cur.fetchall()
```

Expected behavior, a list with tuples for each row in the table with all available columns. However, instead of this, I got a "DEAD" flag from python, with the following line in syslog:

```
Jul 25 09:26:27 my_machine kernel: [8628886.255305] Out of memory: Kill process 25238 (python) score 909 or sacrifice child.
```

The same code works just fine in Python2. I decided to try out querying for less fields. Asking for just 2 fields (ID, Nickname) the code works fine in Python3, so tried out a little more and found out that when my query returns a field that contains a special character on it (such as ç, ã etc) the following error occurs:

```
"pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Some character(s) could not be converted into client's character set.  Unconverted bytes were changed to question marks ('?') (2403) (SQLGetData)")"
```

Did I forgot something when comes to Python3? How can I make my code to work again?

Answer (score 2):

To work with Python3, I had to do this:

```
import pyodbc as db # forgot the imports
conn.setdecoding(db.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
conn.setencoding('latin1')
```

When I informed the encoding my code works with Python3. For some reason Python2 don´t needs it, anyway, I found out while writing this question and decided to share the solution.